# Is there a way to hide a DataTables column based on its type?

Tags: datatables

I have this code currently:

```
drawCallback: function () {
    let api = this.api();
    // hide columns that add up to 0
    api.columns().every(function (i) {
        let sum = this.data().sum();
        if (sum === 0 && typeof sum === 'number' && i !== 0) {
            api.column(i).visible(0);
        }
    });
}
```

There is an issue with it, however... for one particular column where the values are just a single word, such as "Completed" or "Pending", it seems as though `this.data().sum();` will result in 0 rather than NaN.

The first two columns will result in NaN, seemingly because they are multi-word sentences, which is the only difference between these two columns.

This is a sample of the data

```
<td>Foo Bar Jones Jonesy McFoo Department</td>
<td>ABC CityName Location Code XXFOO</td>
<td data-sort="20201002">10/02/2020</td>
<td>Pending</td>
<td>(a variable number of columns with data that is some number that is possibly zero or greater)</td>
```

Isn't there some way to check the column type with `api.columns().every()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to recreate your specific error with single-word cell values vs. multi-word cell values. When I use `parseFloat('x')` vs. `parseFloat('x y z')`, they both evaluate to `NaN`.

(Also, I don't know how you implemented your `sum()` function, so that may explain what you are seeing.)

I am going to use the following example from [here](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/api), as a starting point for my `sum()` - but with a modification:

```js
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'column().data().sum()', function () {
    return this.reduce( function (a, b) {
        var x = parseFloat( a ); // removed the 'or' operator: || 0;
        var y = parseFloat( b ); // removed the 'or' operator: || 0;
        return x + y;
    } );
} );
```

My change (removing the "or" operators) ensures `NaN` values are not set to zero, but remain as `NaN` - which is what you need for your specialized `sum()` function.

Now, if I use this with your DataTable code, and some test data based on what you provided, I get the expected outcome:

[image]

As a side note, dates may be parsed into numbers OK, depending on the data format - which can explain why date columns can show up OK (they sum to a positive number).

Here is the full standalone demo, in case it helps.

In this example, all the data in the final column ("Val 3") are zeros - so that column is hidden. The column remains hidden if there are non-zero values which sum up to zero, also:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Dept</th>
                <th>Loc</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Val 1</th>
                <th>Val 2</th>
                <th>Val 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Foo Bar Jones Jonesy McFoo Department 1</td>
                <td>ABC CityName Location Code XXFOO</td>
                <td data-sort="20200119">19/01/2020</td>
                <td>Active</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Foo Bar Jones Jonesy McFoo Department 2</td>
                <td>DEF CityName Location Code XXFOO</td>
                <td data-sort="20201002">10/02/2020</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Foo Bar Jones Jonesy McFoo Department 3</td>
                <td>XYZ CityName Location Code XXFOO</td>
                <td data-sort="20201016">16/02/2020</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'column().data().sum()', function () {
  return this.reduce( function (a, b) {
    var x = parseFloat( a );
    var y = parseFloat( b );
    return x + y;
  } );
} );

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      drawCallback: function () {
        let api = this.api();
        // hide columns that add up to 0
        api.columns().every(function (i) {
          let sum = this.data().sum();
          if (sum === 0 && typeof sum === 'number' && i !== 0) {
            api.column(i).visible(0);
          }
        });
      }
    } );

  } );


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The sum() function I was using was this one: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum() - this one removes any non-digit character. I've modified it to only remove '$' and ',' and now it works for my purposes.

Comment: I like your solution though, I'll accept it as the answer, and I think your solution is probably more correct.